# Celery and Redis, Cannot connect to redis://redis:6379/0

Tags: python, redis, celery

I am installing celery according to this `[article][1]`.

```
 pip install "celery[redis]"
```

Then made tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://redis:6379/0')
app.conf.result_backend = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    from time import sleep
    sleep(10)
    return x + y
```

And then , test this

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=5
```

error comes.

```
 -------------- celery@koalamac.local v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- macOS-13.2.1-arm64-arm-64bit 2023-04-27 07:23:14
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x104541050
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/0
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 5 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . tasks.add

[2023-04-27 07:23:14,191: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://redis:6379/0: Error 8 connecting to redis:6379. nodename nor servname provided, or not known..
Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)

[2023-04-27 07:23:16,204: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://redis:6379/0: Error 8 connecting to redis:6379. nodename nor servname provided, or not known..
Trying again in 4.00 seconds... (2/100)
```

I can't connect to `redis://redis:6379/0`

Howeber redis-server already works

```
$redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

`'redis://localhost:6379/0'` is the broker URL of Redis that you need to pass to Celery during initialization in `tasks.py`. The `pyamqp://` URI that you provided is for using Celery with AMQP (and not Redis) as the broker (see the [celery docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/index.html) for more information on different backends/brokers).

```py
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Comment: THank you I changed `broker` however error message is the same.

Comment: Can you connect using the regular Redis Python client? 
`pip install redis`, 
`import redis; r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)`

Comment: You could also try running Redis in a docker container `docker run -p 6379:6379 -it redis/redis-stack:latest` (you may need to change the port if your local Redis instance is already using it)

Comment: Does your Redis instance show up in `ss -tulpn` or `netstat -tulpn`? (There should be an entry with `127.0.0.1:6379` and `LISTEN`)